# Python if(xx) in list:

Tags: python, if-statement

```
while True:
    first = input(" : ")
    first.split()
    if("cower" or "fear" or "wait" or "out" or "hide" or "Cower" or "Fear" or "Wait" or "Out") in first:
        print("You hide while all the chaos unfolds outside")
```

#The problem is that this code only checks the first word, if I type "cower" it will print, if I type anything else it will just ask for input again.
#I was only using while True: to not have to reload every time I try the variables.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you try just `"cower" or "fear" or "wait" or "out" or "hide" or "Cower" or "Fear" or "Wait" or "Out"` by itself at the REPL?

Comment: Please check the syntax for `if`. It should be `if ('cower' in first) or ('fear' in first)...:`

Comment: `if first.lower() in ["cower", "fear", "wait", "out", "hide"]:`